# Bookmark to Google Reader for a specific account

Tags: google-reader, google-multi-login

I have multiple Google accounts including a personal account, and a Google Apps account for work.  I want to create a bookmark will send me to my work Google Reader account directly where I have subscribed to several feeds related directly to my job.  Right now I go to http://www.google.com/reader/, then I have to click 'Switch Account' to access the work account.

From my work computer my personal account is logged in as the default and I have used the multiple sign-in feature to login to a couple additional accounts.  The obvious answer would be for me to log into to my work account as default, but I do not want to change my default account to my work account since there are still a couple services not available to Google Apps customers, the multiple sign-in is not fully supported for all Google services, and I use my personal account for more services that I use during the day.

Our Google Apps at work has been updated to use the new infrastructure.

Generic answers that apply to all Google services and not just Google Reader would be very useful.  Google Reader is just the most to me currently, but I would like to create bookmarks to open other services with a specific account.

Answer (score 1):

You can link directly to a Google Apps account for just about any Google service by appending "/a/[domain]" on the end of normal Google URL:

Example, for mydomain.com using Google Apps:

*Google Docs*:
docs.google.com becomes http://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.com

*Google Calendar*:
www.google.com/calendar becomes http://www.google.com/calendar/a/mydomain.com

**The only catch** to this is that I don't believe it works for Google Reader, but rather only for the apps that Google explicitly includes in their Google Apps Suite.

Answer (score 0):

To handle multiple sign-in issues, you may consider using a different browser for a specific account.

You can use the "Note in Reader" bookmarklet (Reader Settings > Goodies) to [create bookmarks within Google Reader with your notes](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-use-google-reader-for.html).

Comment: I know I can use multiple browsers, or even the incognito mode in my browser, but I really want a way so I can go directly open Google Reader for a specific account when I am signed into many accounts.